# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gpus'

Tags: pytorch, gpu

I am trying to play around with pytorch to do generative AI. as shown in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pIMdDWK5sc

I import all as shown:

```
import os

import torch
import torchvision
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, random_split
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pytorch_lightning as pl


random_seed = 42
torch.manual_seed(random_seed)

BATCH_SIZE=128
AVAIL_GPUS = min(1, torch.cuda.device_count())
NUM_WORKERS=int(os.cpu_count() / 2)
```

But when I run the trainer:

```
trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=20, gpus=AVAIL_GPUS)
trainer.fit(model, dm)
```

it shows me the error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gpus'
```

Comment: There is no such parameter in the documentation: https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/common/trainer.html#init

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy You are right! I've checked this and that's so strange. How did the tutorial works then. I'm very confused. It seems to me that it is also a common parameter?
https://www.comet.com/docs/v2/integrations/ml-frameworks/pytorch-lightning/

Comment: @NamTran The syntax for the Trainer has been updated since the video release. Please check out the updated syntax for the Trainer e.g. (devices, accelerator). Check out this GitHub issue as well.  https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/issues/11902.  This works in the video because they are using pytorch-lightning == 1.5.10

Answer (score 5):

https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/common/trainer.html

use trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=20,accelerator="auto")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Sam Joshua.S, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: He has also given the solution, viz to use the "accelarator='auto'" keyword which automatically uses all available GPUs